# Not all jobs available for zip code

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, jobs

In the job search pages, not all jobs show for a zip code search.  I am in the UK, searching for jobs in the US (I am a US citizen).  When I search using my VPN, I can see 13 jobs for a particular zip code, but without it, I can only see 2 jobs.  Is this by design, or is it a bug?

Comment: Is there a "jobs within x miles/kilometers" setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a customer posts a job listing, they have the option to target an advertising region. For instance, a company posting in the US, that isn't offering relocation, visa sponsorship, etc can limit the listing to only North America.

On our end we use GEO targeting to tailor results to the applicant based on the advertising region settings. So in your example, the system is working as intended. When connecting from the UK, we filter out any job listing for the US that aren't targeted for wolrdwide advertisement. Using VPN to get a US based IP gets around that.

Comment: That does seem sort of silly, that there isn't an "I want to move to this location and will pay for it myself, or actually already live there and I'm just on vacation right now" flag override for users?

Comment: Appreciate the explanation, Thank you

Comment: @neminem Some companies don't want to deal with international hires even if they're able to work and will finance their own move. There's also, late start times due to moving, time of at the beginning to get situated, not being able to interview in person, etc. Lots of companies want local hires only. I don't agree with this practice but it's a reality. There's also the benefit of cutting down on spam from international applicants that apply even though they don't have the means to move or need sponsorship.